# extjs 5 record.raw showing mapped fields

Tags: extjs

I got the following model:

```
Ext.define('Thing', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['phase', {name: 'status', mapping: 'phase.status'}]
});
```

Now I load it via a store from the backend. The Server returns:

```
[{phase: {status: 1}}]
```

Now when I do

```
var record = store.get(0);
console.log(record.raw);
```

I get

```
{phase: {status: 1}, status: 1}
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get the real raw data back from the record? Using Extjs 5.1.0.107.

Thanks, Robin

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **real raw** data? What would you like to get?

Comment: The data you get corresponds to the definition of the model. It is expected behavior.

Comment: I though `raw` would return the data that was used to calculate the model data, so in this case only `[{phase: {status: 1}}]` without the calculated field `status`, whereas `data` would return the data corresponding to the definition of the model. Would you mind explaining the difference between `raw` and `data` then?